# DC current limiter micro-amps

Tags: current, dc-dc-converter

Let me start by saying that I'm a student, so I apologize if this is a stupid question.

I have a "power supply" that initially supplies 2 mA of current for a few seconds and then drops down to 100 uA over 30 seconds. I'm trying to find a way to limit the output current from this supply to 100 uA or less, i.e. prevent it from exceeding 100 uA, but every IC that I've checked doesn't allow for this either at the lower limit of quiescent current or the upper limit of quiescent current.

An LDO like the LM317A seems to fit the bill, but I'm worried that this is overkill since the input current is so low and it kills the efficiency when compared to a switching regulator.

I briefly considered using a digital potentiometer controlled via microcontroller, but that's possibly the most complicated way imaginable to tackle this.

Is there a simpler way to limit the current to 100 uA that I'm unaware of? All of the ICs that I've looked at seem like overkill.

EDITED: This power supply is from a small photovoltaic cell. I would prefer to keep the voltage as low as possible, which is around 0.5 volts from the PVC since it's so much easier to add resistance than take it away, but I'm open to any ideas. Think Ti-30 calculators that use a small cell.

Comment: Most regulators will waste more than 100microAmperes.

Comment: We need a few more details. What is the open-terminal output voltage of your PSU? A little bit of info on the application wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: Do you also need to limit the voltage on the load? What's the minimum voltage headroom between the power supply output and the maximum load voltage?

Comment: It's somewhat up in the air at the moment. It's going to a DC-DC step up converter that accepts a very wide range and has adjustable output. As long as it isn't inverted (or can be inverted back) and doesn't exceed 30 Volts, we're good.

Answer (score 2):

Siliconix Application Note [AN103](http://d3i5bpxkxvwmz.cloudfront.net/articles/2011/06/26/fet-current-source-1309146983.pdf) may be of interest.

> The combination of low associated operating voltage and
>   high output impedance makes the FET attractive as a
>   constant-current source. An adjustable-current source (Figure
>   1) may be built with a FET, a variable resistor, and a
>   small battery. For optimum thermal stability, the FET should
>   be biased near the zero temperature coefficient point.

[image]

*Figure 1. Simple FET current source.*

The application note goes into considerable detail so you may find something suitable.

Comment: My education so far has been limited to BJT transistors, so I'll definitely give this a shot. I took apart a "solar powered" calculator to peek at their design and it looked pretty similar to what you're describing, with a small coin battery of some type that I've forgotten. I'm guessing this is a pretty standard design for limiting current in circuits and it works pretty well, I just haven't learned about it.  Thank you.

Comment: This is confusing. What are you actually trying to build?

Comment: It's a sensor that monitors a blinking light for some automated equipment involved with UV curing plastics. Custom tool and die stuff. It's interesting and creative, but when you run into a problem there usually isn't an easy solution to find online. A certain amount of light is transmitted through the plastic during curing, but that light intensity changes as the plastic cures, so once it drops to a certain level, it signals the machine to turn off the UV.

Comment: If you monitor the current produced by the PV cell, then blah blah blah current sensing.

Comment: I think you need to sense current - not limit it. Just monitor the output voltage of the photocell and when it drops below a preset level turn off your lamps. See http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/io/io_4.html for all sorts of photo sensor notes.